# How to shuffle(Arraylist) without displaying a duplicate

Tags: java, android

I want to shuffle an Arraylist and never bring the same result up again.

How do I do that with `Collections.shuffle(myList);`?

If this is answer is posted somewhere else please me know.

**EDIT**

Here is how I am displaying my result
`textView.setText(myList.get(0));`

Comment: Use a Set instead of a List.

Comment: Could you show an example? I've never used a `set` before.

Comment: In what way does Collections.shuffle "bring up the same result again"? Do you mean that the result of the shuffle should never repeat, i.e. no matter how many times you shuffle a deck of cards, they're never in the same order twice? (This is, obviously, not possible)

Comment: @a2800276 correct.

My collection is a list of words, the same word will repeat occasionally.

Comment: Then use a Set, Set<?> ss = new HashSet<?>; ss.addAll(yourList); This will ensure you have no duplicates

Comment: @MikeMilla this doesn't make sense to me, could you provide an example? If your list contains [1,2,3] and you shuffle it, it won't all of the sudden contain [1,1,1]. If the list you're starting contains [1,1,2] then, yeah you may get two 1's in a row. If you don't want that, don't put them in.

Comment: from the result displaying I would infer that you are not really looking for shuffling, but just selecting a random item in the list, except not the same twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the ideas and suggestions!

My issue was silly.

`textView.setText(myList.get(order++));` fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.shuffle` does not provide that functionality. You need to do a separate deduplication step. A [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) would provide that function.

```
Set s = new HashSet(myList.size());
s.addAll(myList);
List shuffledList = new ArrayList(s.size());
shuffledList.addAll(s)
// Since items come out of a set in an undefined order, using shuffledList
// in this state may suit your needs. otherwise go ahead and shuffle it too
Collections.shuffle(shuffledList)
return shuffledList;
```

Here is [a more advanced question on deduplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755632/finding-duplicate-entries-in-collection).

Answer (score 0):

Collections.shuffle will just shuffle the list passed. Its not maintaining any previous state. So if you want to avoid duplicate you'll have to keep a state of previously generated list and compare. Alternatively you could find all possible combination and the access that list one by one. [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library has methods to find combinations. `Collections2.permutations(myList)` e.g.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;

public class Shuffle {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}));
        for(List<String> list : Collections2.permutations(myList)){
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }

}
```

This will give all non-repeating shuffles.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just want to display a random value of a list, in this case use that (no need to shuffle the whole list):

```
int rand = (int)(array.size()*Math.random());
textView.setText(myList.get(rand));
```

EDIT:

Use this function with a global tmp variable:

```
private List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
private String getRandom(List<String> myList){
    if (tmpList.size()<=0) tmpList = new ArrayList<String>(myList);
    int rand = (int)(tmpList.size()*Math.random());
    return tmpList.remove(rand);
}
```

and set the value as:

```
textView.setText(getRandom(myList));
```

Comment: Correct.

This code works, but I am still displaying a duplicate result on occasion.

Say my list is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

I never want to generate the same number twice.

Comment: Then remember what you displayed the last time and if it comes up again, pick the next item. Alternatively, keep the whole shuffled list around and display one item after the other. Unless you've put duplicates in your list, you won't get duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an additional list that stores previously used items. Each time you get an item, you can check if it has already been used (and if so, skip it). This way, you can preserve the original items chances of being used. If you have 10 A's, and a B, and you shuffle them, you have a higher chance of the A showing up first...etc. If you do not want this functionality, than I recommend using a set.

```
ArrayList<String> used = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> items = getItems();
Collections.shuffle(items);

public String getItem() {
  if(items.length == 0)
    return null;
  item = items.remove(0);
  if(used.contains(item)) 
    return getItem();
  return used.add(item)
}
```

In the case of using a set

```
HashSet<String> items = new HashSet<String>(getItems());
Collections.shuffle(items);

public String getItem() {
  return items.remove(0);
}
```